# Bound function gets called multiple times over different components

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue-select for custom select inputs and bind a function on the `selected` property like:

```
<VueNextSelect  :selected="checkTimeout(inputData,...) ><VueNextSelect/>
```

I'm using the component including VueNextSelect multiple times in my form. When now selecting a value the function `checkTimeout` gets called as much as the number of select-inputs instead of just once. Even tho the component is in a different instance.

Could this be a problem of binding the function to `selected`? When using other inputs with e.g. `@change.prevent` the function gets just called once.

Comment: is it this component? https://vue-select.org I don't see `:selected` as an option https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting

Comment: @Kunukn No, it's this one: https://iendeavor.github.io/vue-next-select/api-reference.html .
Cause vue-select makes problems with Vue3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for selected event is this.

```html
<VueNextSelect  @selected="checkTimeout(inputData,...) />
```

https://iendeavor.github.io/vue-next-select/api-reference.html#selected

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that somehow. Sometimes it's the little bugs we don't see. ^^